# Loading a page into a dialog Multiple Links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have this code from http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I have a page that has several links on it that open up a jquery modal with a form inside, with this code it only allows me to open up the first link in the pop up, everything link after it is displayed in a new page..

I understand that each link has to have its own id, but I'm not sure how to rewrite this to open multiple links on the same page (not at the same time)

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: instead of using ids use class and change $('#page-help').each(function() { to $('.page-help').each(function() {